# How to display contents of multi upload files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here, there is an example to show contents of one upload file.

.js

```
$scope.uploadFilename = function (files) {
          if (!files[0]) {
            return;
          }

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            var str = reader.result;
            var csv = str.split(/\n/);
            var headers = csv[0].split(',');
            var str_result = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < csv.length - 1; i++) {
              var curline = csv[i].split(',');
              var tmp = '' + curline[1];
              if (i == csv.length - 2) {
                str_result += tmp.split('"').join('');
              } else {
                str_result += tmp.split('"').join('') + '\n';
              }
            }
            angular.element('#upload_keywords_list').val(str_result);
            $scope.uploadedKeywordsCount = csv.length - 2;
          };
          reader.readAsText(files[0]);
        };
```

.html

```
<div class="chosefile">
              <div class="clearfix">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="pull-left" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFilename(this.files)">
<textarea id="upload_keywords_list" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
              <div class="uploaded-keywords-count" ng-if="uploadedKeywordsCount > 0">
                <strong>Total number: </strong>{{ uploadedKeywordsCount }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want to show contents of multi upload files.
Can you tell me the method how to do it?
And then, how to change the value of total number, when i edit the contents of textarea that I've already opened?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select multiple files at once, or one by one?

Comment: I want to select multi files at once.

Comment: I made it just below. Run the snippet and you'll see.

Comment: can you divide into .html and .js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works.

I removed `uploaded-keywords-count` and `textarea` from your html. And added a new **div**

`<div id="textAreaContainer"></div>`

Also i made changes to your script. I wrapped your code inside `for loop`
Now, you can select multiple files, **at once** or **one by one** it doesn't matter.

And if you try to select the same file again, it warns you. and rejects the file again.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="fileApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('fileApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        var allFiles = [];
        $scope.uploadFilename = function (files) {
          if (!files[0]) {
            return;
          }

          cnt = files.length;
          for (var k = 0; k < cnt; k++) {
            if(!allFiles.includes(files[k].name)) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.fileName = files[k].name;
              allFiles.push(reader.fileName);
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            var str = e.target.result;
            var csv = str.split(/\n/);
            var headers = csv[0].split(',');
            var str_result = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < csv.length - 1; i++) {
              var curline = csv[i].split(',');
              var tmp = '' + curline[1];
              if (i == csv.length - 2) {
                str_result += tmp.split('"').join('');
              } else {
                str_result += tmp.split('"').join('') + '\n';
              }
            }
            $scope.uploadedKeywordsCount = csv.length - 2;
            var containerData = "";
            containerData += '<div id="fileContent' + k + '"><textarea>' + str_result + '</textarea>';
            containerData += '<span>' + $scope.uploadedKeywordsCount + '</span></div>'
            var containerHtml = $(containerData);
            angular.element('#textAreaContainer').append(containerHtml);
          };
          reader.readAsText(files[k]);
          //console.log(files[k]);
        } else {
          alert('File already exists');
        }

      }
    }
  });
      $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function(){
        $(this).closest("div").find('span').html($(this).val().split(/\n/).length);
      })
    </script>


    <div class="chosefile">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="pull-left" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFilename(this.files)" multiple>
        <div id="textAreaContainer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

> I forgot to tell you that i added a new script for your second question. Now you can edit the textarea, and the lines count changes.

Comment: It doesn't work. In your code, what is $(this).closest("div")?

Comment: `<div id="textAreaContainer"></div>`

Comment: yes. of course, your method is good. But in my case, I want to make codes like above style, that is, codes must be divided into .js and .html. Can you please do like that?

Comment: Yes of course, but i really couldn't get the point. You can divide it into two parts yourself. **.JS** is the part between `<script>` and `</script>` tags. And **HTML** part is the part which starts with `<div class="chosefile">` and end with `</div>` There is no other way to that. Sorry but do you have some knowledge on HTML and Javascript.

Comment: of course. That's not why, how can i make the codes and develop the sites? At that time, I was asleep and so I'm sorry. I think people have three seconds when they mistake in a day. When I sent that comment, it was just that. It does work well now. Thanks so much. P.S In my case, you're good guy. I think we can be good friends. What about that?

Comment: :) Glad it works. We can be good friends, if you love Gheorghe Hagi like i do. He was the best. And Popescu too. They were great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143098/discussion-between-c-petrescu-and-ruzgar).